# Object arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, object

So, I have this code:

```
public void add(Student student) {
    if(currentSize == arraySize){
        arraySize *= 2;
        Student[] pomArray = memoryArray;
        memoryArray = new Student[arraySize];
        for(int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++){
            memoryArray[i] = pomArray[i];
        }
    }
    memoryArray[currentSize] = student;
    currentSize++;
```

Basically, if `currentSize` gets big as `arraySize`, I need to make new array twice as big and copy all data in it. What I dont understand is the way this new array was made.
I'd do :

```
student[] pomArray = new Student[arraySize]
```

or something between those lines.
I don't understand what does `student[] pomArray = memoryArray` .

Also line `memoryArray[Currentsize] = student`.

It would be the best if you guys could guide me to a place where this is well explained, I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Read about array initialization here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: have a look at the [java util  implementation of arraylist](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html)

Comment: student[] pomArray = memoryArray creates a new Student array and assing the memoryArray values to it. memoryArray[Currentsize] = student assigns the new Student passed to the method to the first empty position of the Array.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be easier if you use collections, they expand and reduce as you add and delete entries besides collections classes provide more useful methods than arrays. For example:

```
//Importing Collections    
import java.util.Collection; 

import java.util.List;

import java.util.ArrayList;

//use this to create arraylist

List<Student> Studentlist = new ArrayList<Student>();

Student Student1 = new Student();

Studentlist.add(Student1);

With this you need not bother about expanding;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this, you can use Collections.

[Java List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

For example:

```
List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
Student student1 = new Student();
list.add(student1);
```

Comment: Since it is a fair advise, he is asking for clarifications rather than other options. It's clear that he didn't write the code since he doesn't know what it does.

Comment: Upvote for you ;) but maybe is good to show a different way for someone who just started to work with Java ;)

Answer (score 1):

- The line `Student[] pomArray = memoryArray` makes the `pomArray` reference the same location referenced by `memoryArray`.
- Then the `memoryArray`'s size is doubled by creating a new array and the contents of `pomArray` is copied back to `memoryArray`.
- Then the new element to be added to the array is stored in `student` and this is added to the array.

Comment: So basically I need to make new array to store all the data since doubling the size of my current array will make new array somewhere else in the memory and it will end up empty? I can't just widen my current array while preserving all previous data?

Comment: yeah, arrrays are fixed in size and their size cannot be modified. so you need to create a new array, copy the values from the old array and then add items to the new array. You can also have to set the old array to `null` so that it can be garbage collected.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining, I assumed java had something like realloc in C where it would automatically find new place in memory and copy everything you had in that array so far.

Comment: well, java does not need that since, if the arrays are going to be reallocated frequently, then there are the `Collections` classes which can be used for that purpose, where you don't need to give a specific size.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Student[] pomArray = memoryArray; // copying memoryArray into pomArray(temp array)
memoryArray[currentSize] = student; // the current student is added as the last valid item in the array.
```

Generally you need to read about arrays.